# Gridview in .Net Core Razor

Tags: gridview, .net-core, razor-pages

I'm new to .NET Core and Razor pages, previously I was using Web Forms.    Is there an alternative to the Gridview control that was available in Web Forms?

Comment: What do you use GridView for? If you use it mostly for displaying records and some sorting with EntityFramework or EF Core, have you looked at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-rp/sort-filter-page?view=aspnetcore-2.2?

Comment: I'm not aware of a dedicated control for that (I miss it too). However, it appears it is fairly simple to [implement such functionality manually](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Implement-Grid-GridView-in-ASPNet-Core-Razor-Pages.aspx) or use [data tables](https://github.com/dmamulashvili/DataTables-with-Razor-Pages)..